# .NET dropdownlists with huge number of items

Tags: asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu, postback

I am working on a webpart which makes use of 5 dropdowns (each dropdown represents 'Project' table columns like projectNo, ProjectPM, ContractNo etc). The table has more than 3000 items, so when the dropdownlists are finally databound, they have more than 3000 items to load, which pretty much brings IE to a halt.

What is the best way to go about architecting a solution, so users can still make use of the dropdown list interface, may be like first rendering an empty dropdownlist and then using a modal window to first find the project number they are looking for and then set the item as selected in the dropdownlist. I am envisioning the following UI. Can anyone guide me on how I should go about solving this issue?

```
    -------------------
                    |V|   [SearchBtn]
    -------------------

    -------------------
                    |V|    [SearchBtn]
    -------------------

    -------------------
                    |V|    [SearchBtn]
    -------------------



   [FindProjectBtn]
```

Clickikng on the searchBtn basically brings up a popup window where they can search for their stuff, and when they click on the matched result, it will set the dropdownlist.

Comment: I suppose it depends on information outside the scope of this immediate problem. Hard to determine whether it would be good as a grid that allowed searching/sorting/paging with the ability to go to a details page for a specific item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with dropdown lists, a good rule-of-thumb is to keep the list short so you do not experience browser performance issues.  If you have thousands of items to look through you can:

- Create a search component whereby the user enters a part of the project name they are searching for and display a simple grid for them to choose from.
- Implement a type-ahead mechanism.  The user enters the first couple of letters of what they are searching for.  You can query your DB for the top 10 hits and return them via AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3000 items, then definitely drop down list will not be a right designing decision.

using any kind of repeater lists with paging, sorting and searching functions is highly recommended in your case.

but if you insist to have a kind of drop down list view then `Matthew's suggestions` are your answer.